# android how to make accessible data folder content to other application

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want to open a pdf file saved in application data folder using pdf viewer application. How can i make accessible data folder content to other application. Some code snippet will help me lot.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                 intent.setDataAndType( Uri.parse("content://" + pdf_path), "application/pdf" );
                 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: If by *"application data folder"* you mean the internal memory, then this isn't possible. The internal memory allocated to an app is private and cannot be accessed by any other apps. To do what you want, you will need to copy the file to the SD card and provide an absolute path for the `Uri`.

Comment: @Squonk can we do using content provider?

Comment: @Squonk - In internal storage of application if file has a `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` permission then its possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
File file = new File(“/sdcard/read.pdf”);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),”application/pdf”);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

You can access pdf file from external memory by this.make sure you are giving correct path of it.

Comment: I was using Uri.parse which the external pdf readers didn't seem to like. Switching to Uri.fromFile worked for me thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure your `.pdf` file has, `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` Permission like,

Now to access `.pdf` file from application data folder means, `/data/data/<package_Name>/`

Use, `getFilesDir()` which returns the path of Application data directory,

Then,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(getFilesDir()+ "pdf_path")),"application/pdf" );
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: How do I set the `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` permission on a file?